# Using base.html.twig as the default layout in Symfony2 in a DRY way

Tags: symfony

I have a very simple problem: I have a Symfony2 app and it's not using the base layout file, base.html.twig. What does it take to get your app to use this layout? Seems like it should just use it automatically.

Edit: I've found that if I put `{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}` at the top of any layout file, and then put `{% block body %}` and `{% endblock %}` around my content, it will use `base.html.twig`. However, I've so far only figured out how to do this on a per-file basis. If you have to do this include on every single template for which you want to use it, that would be astonishingly stupid, and I can't imagine that that's the case, given how well the DRY principle is applied everywhere else in Symfony.

**So the more specific version of my question is: how can I get Symfony to use base.html.twig globally, in a DRY way?**

Comment: If base.html.twig was used for all the templates, you would not be able to include a single template to another one nor render any sub-requests into another template. What would you do if you had a template that doesn't need to be extending the base template?

Comment: So just for some clarity for a SF2 newbie - is this still the case in later versions of SF2 (as of April 2014)? Considering I need the `<html>` on every top-level template do I have to extend `base.html.twig`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It looks like I've found the answer to my question, although I sincerely hope I'm wrong. According to [this section of the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#three-level-inheritance), you have to include that `extends` thing on every template page! I just puked all over my computer.

Edit: To be clear, the answer to my question, evidently, is that it's not possible.

Comment: Did you read the docs carefully? You have a base.html.twig, you extend this in your layout.html.twig and extend this in the specific templates you want to use it.

Comment: Yes, I read that part. Doesn't that still have me adding an `extends` to every single template individually?

Comment: Yes, I guess there is no shortcut to that.

Comment: Yes, in the same way that you have to put `class ConcreteExample implements InterfaceExample` whenever you want to use an interface. It takes, what, 5 seconds to import it from a macro? It makes the code more self-documenting, and more flexible.

Answer (score 5):

First, you should understand what Twig templates compile to — classes. Then, imagine, that what you're asking for is like asking how to make all your plain PHP classes extend some basic class without writing `extends` in your code. Does it sound like a good idea?

Comment: I get what you mean. It seems, then, that the way Symfony should handle this is to automatically include an `extends` in every template, the same way Symfony and Doctrine automatically include an `extends` in the PHP class files they generate.

Comment: But what if I dont't want to extend base/layout template in every file?

Comment: Then just change the code to tell it to extend whatever you want to extend. I'd rather have to change a sensible default a few times than have to manually paste the `extends` a bunch of times.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to accomplish this. It isn't advisable, but it is possible.

```
twig:
    base_template_class: Path\To\Base\TemplateClass
```

It's possible you might run in to problems though. Symfony2 also has template that aren't meant to use a base template so you might have to look into a way to override this feature for system templates.

I would look at [the docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html) and also [this](http://linuxer.googlecode.com/hg-history/a6ce35cd673f0b19c1d4afa6f89c55f139c96b78/docs/fabpot-Twig-c0334a3/doc/06-Recipes.markdown). They both talk about using this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i had raised [this](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/831) issue in github, and this is what fabpot had to say

> The layout is part of the template and belongs there. You should be
>   able to do whatever you want with it with variables and if you want to
>   conditionally extend a template, have a look here:
>   http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#making-a-layout-conditional

So, bottomline is we cannot do that, or we shouldn't be doing that and if we are doing that, we are doing it wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a workaround. A good tip it's to save a macro in your editor and load it automatically for `twig` files. Then, when you need it apply it and you'll save a lot of keystrokes. It's not DRY for the code at all but it's for your fingers, and I prefer doing that way instead of modifying symfony core.

Following is the macro for VIM. Put this in `.vimrc`, reload vim and in your `twig` file run `@t` in normal mode:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *html.twig let @t="ggO{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}\033o{% block body %}\033Go{% endblock %}\033gg"
```